# How to find a file with the "/" in the filename?

Tags: macos, command-line, filenames, rar

I've created a RAR, but by a mistake its filename consisted of "/". The command looks like this:

```
rar m -m0 Promo-CD-R/ Promo-CD-R/
```

The RAR archiver output first line was:

```
Creating archive Promo-CD-R/.rar
```

Now I can't see and can't find the archive. What to do?
I work on macOS.

Answer (score 1):

`Promo-CD-R/.rar` is a folder ‘Promo-CD-R’ with one file in it with the name ‘.rar’. Since the filename begins with a dot, it's a hidden file. You can rename the file using `mv`:

```
mv Promo-CD-R/.rar Promo-CD-R/newfilename.rar
```

You can then open the Promo-CD-R folder in Finder and see the archive.

Comment: It doesn't work. :( Looks like this archive dissapeared in /dev/null or something...

$ mv Promo-CD-R/.rar Promo-CD-R.rar
mv: rename Promo-CD-R/.rar to Promo-CD-R.rar: No such file or directory

Comment: That's not what the answer said to do... `Promo-CD-R/newfilename.rar`

Comment: @user793900 I have replicated the issue (in Debian though) and it matches this answer perfectly. Are you sure you `mv` the right thing? I've seen the first version of your question and I think your `Promo-CD-R` just obfuscates the *real* path. `cd` to the directory and run `ls -a` or `ls .rar` to see the file.

Comment: I did this before I asked my question. Both commands display "No such file or directory". What do you mean by "Promo-CD-R just obfuscates the real path"?

Comment: Tetsujin, you're right. But still      mv: rename Promo-CD-R/.rar Promo-CD-R/new.rar: No such file or directory